# How to populate a complex list with sublist from SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a structure of lists that I would like to populate from database. I've already mapped all tables and insertion methods. However I don't know what is the best approach to get all those data and populate my Java Objects. I have this structure:

```
public class DailySchedule {
    private long id;
    private List<Task> tasks;
    private List<Plan> plans;
}

public class Task {
    private long id;
    private long duration;
    private String description;
    private Date date;
}

public class Plan {
    private long id;
    private String description;
    private Date date;
    private List<User> users;
}

public class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Should I create a huge INNERJOIN and get all the data (including repeated info) and try to populate the Java Objects or I should get all the Id's from each table and perform a loop in Java(using cursor) and perform Selects by ID's and populate the tables?

Comment: Cursor would be a better idea, since they were created pretty much for this exact scenario - iterating over results from DB queries

Comment: In this approach I am going to iterate rows with a lot of unnecessary data (results of InnerJoins). Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have below tables

- daily_schedule
- task
- plan
- user

Code

```
public List<DailySchedule> getDailySchedules(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDataBase();
    Cursor dailyScheduleCursor = db.rawQuery(“Select * from daily_schedule ”);
    List<DailySchedule> all = new ArrayList<>();
    While(dailyScheduleCursor.next()){
        DailySchedule dailySchedule = new DailySchedule();
        dailySchedule.setId(dailyScheduleCursor.getLong(0));
        dailySchedule.setTasks(getTasks(dailyScheduleCursor.getLong(0)));
        dailySchedule.setPlans(getTasks(dailyScheduleCursor.getLong(0)));
        all.add(dailySchedule);
      }
    db.close();
}
public List<Task> getTasks(int id ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDataBase();
    Cursor taskCursor = db.rawQuery(“Select * from tasks where id =’”+id+”’ ”);
    List<Task> all = new ArrayList<>();
    While(taskCursor.next()){
        Task task = new task();
        task.setId(taskCursor.getLong(0));
        // set other attributes     
        all.add(task);
    }
    db.close();
   return all;


}

public List<Plan> getPlan(int id ){

    getUser(id);// get all plans
    // set user
    return plans;
}
public User(int id){
       //create user from data
    return user;
}
```

Then call `getDailySchedules()` from somewhere.

Note If you want to see your SQLite databse content, use 
[AndroidDBvieweR](https://github.com/thedathoudarya/AndroidDBvieweR)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking to implement the same solution but I was not sure if it the best approach. Do you know if there is any better solution?